# Code in C where it prints from 0 to 100 then asks if user wants to see it again

Tags: c, printing, numbers

I'm trying to make a program in C where it prints from 0 to 100 then asks the user to print it again. It's not working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int num;
    char resposta[0];

    resposta[0] = 's';
    num = 0;

    do
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            num += 1;
            printf("%i\n", num);
            printf("Repetir?s/n\n");
            scanf("%c", resposta[0]);
        }

    } while ((strcmp(resposta[0], "S") == 0) || (strcmp(resposta[0], "s") == 0));

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues.

1. You have an array that can contains 0 elements which is rather pointless, you want `char resposta[1]`.
2. But you don't want an array of chars anyway. You're using the `%c` specifier you need a single `char` instead of an array of `char`s.
3. You're mixing up strings and chars. Change `strcmp(resposta[0], "S")==0` to `resposta == 'S'`, provided you have declared `char resposta;`.
4. You're asking the user if he wants to start over again in the for loop which is probably not what you want.

Basically you want this (untested code):

```
int main() {
  char resposta;
  resposta = 's';
  int num = 0;

  do {
    num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      num += 1;
      printf("%i\n", num);
    }

    printf("Repetir?s/n\n");
    scanf("%c", &resposta);    // not the useage of the & operator here
  } while (resposta == 'S' || resposta == 's');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

when declaring an array in C, the number in the brackets `[]` is not the index number, it is the total number of elements contained within the array. Setting `char resposta[0];` means that resposta contains no elements.

This is different from when *accessing* elements, which uses a zero-index. So running `scanf("%c", resposta[0]);` is trying to access the first element, but there are zero elements within resposta, so that's likely why this isn't working.

I also figure I should add that it is entirely possible to just create a `char` variable that is not an array, since it seems you only need the one character. Just do `char resposta;` without the brackets.

Some more info on Arrays if you're interested: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/c/c_arrays.php)

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons it is not working is that the program stops to ask the user to continue **inside** the loop. Another failure is that the counter being used is not **reset to zero** for the second and subsequent runs. Another failure is the **scanf format specifier** that does not clear the *newline* out of the input buffer. The next 'get input' will not find an S/s to continue, but will pickup a LF and terminate the loop.

Things can be simplified if they are separated. The interaction with the user is very clearly defined and should be factored-out into its own function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int again(void) {
    puts( "Repetir? " );
    char ch;
    return scanf( " %c", &ch ) == 1 && (ch == 'S' || ch == 's' );
}

// Edit: Just noticed the OP title says "0 to 100"
void out(void) { 
    int i = 0; 
    while( i <= 100 ) printf( "%i\n", i++ ); 
}

int main() {
    do out(); while( again() );
    return 0;
}
```